# DeviseAuthToken Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

I'm using `DeviseTokenAuth` and I can't figure out why:

```
warden.user(rc.to_s.underscore.to_sym)
```

is returning me `nil` in `set_user_by_token.rb` (a file of the gem).

I've `print rc.to_s.underscore.to_sym` which is returning `"user"`.

What's going out here? How can I debug that?

Comment: Is adding a debugger like [`byebug`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) an option?

Comment: It's not helping because warden should be a class hidden in devise file, but I can't see what's happening there

Comment: I overload the file using a "like" request but gem method should be more efficient